Telebot. @bot.callback_query_handler isn't working
Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong? The bot sends me an inline keyboard, but after clicking the button, I do not receive any callbacks (even the logger doesn't send anything).
Also, if I pass URL to inlineKeyboardButton it works properly
@bot.message_handler()
def add_city(message):
    if user_status[message.chat.id] == Statuses.AddCity:
        logger.info("User adding the city")
        request = {
            "name": message.text
        }
        response = requests.post(f'{api_url}/api/users/{message.chat.id}/add-city', json=request, headers=headers)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            logger.info("User got city. Waiting for confirmation")
            data = response.json()
            user_status[message.chat.id] = Statuses.ConfirmCity
            markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Confirm", callback_data="Confirm"))
            markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Deny", callback_data="Deny"))

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{data.get("name")}')
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Підтверди що це саме те місто, яке ти хотів додати:',
                                   reply_markup=markup)
        else:
            logger.info("Bad Request")
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Виникла помилка при додаванні міста :(')

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ("Confirm", "Deny"))
def handle_city_confirmation(call):
    logger.info(call)
    if user_status[call.message.chat.id] == Statuses.ConfirmCity:

        if call.data.split(' ')[0] == "Confirm":
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'success')
        else:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "deny")
    else:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "fail")




The solution was updating the token. Hope it will help someone
